# why does 'terraform plan' fail due to my timezone not set to automatic?

Tags: terraform

I had issue

```
terraform plan
╷
│ Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating 
provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: operation error STS: 
GetCallerIdentity, https response error 
StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 4772c754-fcc4-4933-85c7-f36407f51c74, 
api error SignatureDoesNotMatch: Signature expired: 20220214T143902Z is now earlier 
 than 20220214T152434Z (20220214T153934Z - 15 min.)
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on main.tf line 2, in provider "aws":
│    2: provider "aws" {
```

i found resolve here in this [github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/14873). Why does it even depend on system time date?! I use win10.

when i set it to automatic it worked - wonder why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hashicorp/aws` provider must send requests to the AWS API that are signed using the [AWS Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) algorithm.

One of the goals of the AWS signing scheme is to minimize the time window that a compromised signature couuld be reused by an attacker. To achieve that, the signature scheme includes a timestamp when the signature was created and the remote system requires that the timestamp be within 15 minutes of the request time as understood by the remote system.

The official documentation describes this as follows, at the time I'm writing this:

> - **Protect against reuse of the signed portions of the request** – The signed portions (using AWS Signatures) of requests are valid within 15 minutes of the timestamp in the request. An unauthorized party who has access to a signed request can modify the unsigned portions of the request without affecting the request's validity in the 15 minute window. Because of this, we recommend that you maximize protection by signing request headers and body, making HTTPS requests to Amazon S3, and by using the s3:x-amz-content-sha256 condition key (see [Amazon S3 Signature Version 4 Authentication Specific Policy Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/bucket-policy-s3-sigv4-conditions.html)) in AWS policies to require users to sign Amazon S3 request bodies.

If your local system has an incorrect system time or if your system believes its local time to be in a different timezone than you are actually working in then the AWS SDK (which the Terraform AWS provider is built with) will generate a timestamp outside of the allowed 15 minute window, and so your request will fail. This would be true of any request to AWS APIs using this standard signature scheme, whether made by Terraform's AWS provider or by any other AWS-integrated tool.

In order for requests to succeed your system must be able to generate a correct UTC-referenced timestamp. In order for that to be true, it must have both a correct time and – if you are using an operating system like Windows where the system time is stored in local time rather than UTC – a correct configuration of your system time's offset from UTC so that the SDK can convert to a UTC timestamp as the AWS API requires.